# Maintaining web-application version number

Tags: version

I want some suggestions about web-application versioning system. 
Currently I use SVN commit number as version number of the application. So if the commit number is around 596 then I call it version 5.96

What is the most used approach for keeping a transparent versioning system of web application?

Answer (score 2):

Check out 'semantic versioning'

It's a pretty popular standard these days.

Essentially version numbers consist of three numbers

major.minor.patch

major version is only updated any time you are doing a major release which has 'breaking' changes in it (essentially 3rd party integrating with your site will need to adjust their code for it to work with yours again)

minor version is updated when you are adding non-breaking changes

patch version is updated when you check in any small changes/bug fixes.

If the major version gets reset then the other two go back to zero. So you might be at 3.1.17 and when you move to 4 it becomes 4.0.0 then you might do a small bug fix so it goes to 4.0.1 the  you might add a small feature and it goes to 4.1.0 and another bug fix so it goes and another bug fix so it goes to 4.1.1 and another feature so it changes to 4.2.0 etc.

My explanation isn't perfect so go look it up. It's a pretty sensible versioning system and allows anyone using your library / integrating with you to instantly know whether or not to expect breaking changes, new functionality or bug fixes.